# MVC Routes - Mixing Api and View Type Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI project that also serves up a documentation page using the MCV.Explorer library and I cannot fathom out how to add a route to this controller.

The Api controllers are working as expected with this route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have a docs controller inside a "Docs" directory within the API application like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
public class DocsController : Controller
{
  [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
    return View(apiExplorer);
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to route to it with:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Docs",
  url: "Docs/",
  defaults: new { controller = "Docs", action = "Index" }
);
```

The site just errors complaining that directory browsing isn't enabled. I'm guessing there is something happening due to the controller class not being in the Controllers directory but I'm not sure on that front.

I also have on the Home ApiController with a simple method (Index) that at the moment returns a couple of links.  How would you set up a route to handle the home\index route for an ApiController?

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public Link[] Index()
  {
    return new Link[] 
    { 
      new SelfLink(Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, "mood-api-root"),
      new Link("auth", @"Account/Login/", "authenticate")
    };
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going down the route (no pun) of switching to using AttributeRouting using the NuGet package:

```
Install-Package AttributeRouting.Webapi
```

Switched to this and I've not looked back.  Really nice solution to routing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why your `/Docs` route isn't working properly but it's likely that it is not registered properly. Look at the [configuration code](https://github.com/SixtoSaez/PhillySNUG) for the [documentation of this Web API sample web site](http://phillysnug.apphb.com/help). This web site integrates both ASP.NET MVC & Web API functionality into a single project. It uses ASP.NET MVC Areas but the routing code should be similar even if you don't use areas.

Comment: Thanks Sixto, whilst areas are interesting ideas it doesn't really make any sense, my routes afaik should be working as is.  There shouldn't be any additional config needed to tell mvc where my controller is.  Still trying to get this working ... :(

Comment: For troubleshooting, try removing all the Web API routes and leave just the MVC route configured to see if it works. If it does then one of the Web API routes is overriding the MVC route. Just an idea.